# Nginx proxy for CNAME setup

Tags: nginx, regular-expressions

My application serves landing pages and we need users to custom CNAME it

eg: {{userdomain}}.myapp.com/{{pageid}} serves the landing pages today.

User wants to map it to {{landing}}.theirsite.com

So, we allow them to cname it to {{userdomain}}-{{pageid}}.myapplanding.com

I am trying to use nginx as proxy the requests to the page. Another reason for me to use nginx is to allow SSL certs by the user as it's difficult to configure on the cloud service we use for myapp.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.myapplanding.com;
    # server_name {{userdomain}}-{{pageid}}.myapplanding.com (I want userdomain and pageid to be parsed and proxied

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://????; // What goes here? It should forward to https://{{userdomain}}.myapp.com/landing/{{pageid}}
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You need to make this much more concrete. How do you expect to embed a URL path (pageid) into a DNS label?

Comment: There will be runtime instructions to provide the pageid which the users will setup in their DNS.

Comment: Or I can add a http header of the request and let the end app serve the page looking at this header.

Comment: Your server will get `{{landing}}.theirsite.com` as `Host` and will have no idea what `pageid` or `userdomain` are.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we asked all users to cname it to landing.myapp.com; nginx proxy got the request URI and sent it to the upstream server which looked up the db and served the right page. There was no custom cname for each user.